# Parse doesn't update a specific class

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, save

I've got a very strange problem...
I have a button that needs to clean all the QR-cards in the parse database. I have a class **QRCard** for this and updating this class doesn't work, I created a new class **Test** and didn't change anything in the code beside classname and here it works perfectly...
I checked the ACL settings on both but they're identically.
I cleared my cache etc, but nothing helps, I also deleted en recreated the class but didn't work either. Anyone has a idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
function clearAllQR() {
var QRCard = Parse.Object.extend("QRCard");     
var query = new Parse.Query(QRCard);

query.find({
    success: function(results) {    

    var emptyArr = new Array();     
    var updateArray = new Array();

    for (i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        results[i].set("aankopen", emptyArr);
        updateArray.push(results[i]);
    }

    console.log(results);

    Parse.Object.saveAll(updateArray, {
        success: function(list) {
        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        },
      });
},
error: function(object, error) {}
});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't have [Class Level Permission](http://docs.parseplatform.org/parse-server/guide/#class-level-permissions).

Remove it using Parse Dashboard or make your call with **masterKey**